# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vba

I got this error and not able to solve this please someone reply.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

```
Dim cnnOLEDB As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cmdOLEDB As New OleDbCommand
    Dim cmdInsert As New OleDbCommand
    Dim cmdUpdate As New OleDbCommand
    Dim cmdDelete As New OleDbCommand
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand

Dim cnn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\project\B-tech\FirstVBproject\LMSapp\LMSapp\Library2.accdb")




cnn.open()
Dim Bid, Bnmbr, bname, bauthor, Bdscptn, bcate, bpus, bprice, btype, byear, bpage, pcopy As String

    'Dim catename, catdes As String
    Dim insert As String
    Bnmbr = BNBRTXT.Text
    bname = TextBox1.Text
    bauthor = TextBox2.Text
    Bdscptn = TextBox3.Text
    bpus = TextBox4.Text
    bprice = TextBox5.Text
    byear = TextBox6.Text
    bpage = TextBox7.Text
    pcopy = TextBox8.Text


    'catdes = TextBox3.Text
    insert = "INSERT INTO book (BookNumber,Name,Author,Descraption,Publication,Price,Year,Pages,Copy) VALUES ('" & Bnmbr & "','" & bname & "','" & bauthor & "','" & Bdscptn & "','" & bpus & "','" & bprice & "','" & byear & "','" & bpage & "','" & pcopy & "'   )"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(insert, cnn)
    cmdOLEDB = New OleDbCommand(insert, cnn)
    cnn.GetType()

    cmdOLEDB.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("data inserted", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    BNBRTXT.Text = ""
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    TextBox3.Text = ""
    TextBox4.Text = ""
    TextBox5.Text = ""
    TextBox6.Text = ""
    TextBox7.Text = ""
    TextBox8.Text = ""


    cnn.close()
```

Comment: You really should use prepared Statements.. I guess your input from the textboxes is destroying your query.. Please post the textbox content as well.

Comment: i had write all right statement but why this occer

Comment: Is BookNumber a string and not a number? Is BookNumber an auto-increment field and Primary Key?

Comment: no it's not a primary keyit's a text field  only

Comment: Please, please, please learn to use parameters. A user could type "Drop Table book" into one of those text boxes and someone would be looking for a new job.

Comment: Try putting brackets around [Name] NAME is a reserved word. Is Descraption also misspelled in the database? Should be Description. Are all the fields strings?

Comment: yess all fields is string and in the database  all are short text

Comment: thanks a lot mary it's a problem with brackets []

Comment: This is why it is goot to use prepared statements: [XKCD 327](https://xkcd.com/327/)